# Regular Expression to Match character at a position and ignore characters after

Tags: java, regex

Want to match the character at position 7 to either be - or an Uppercase letter

This is what I have ^.{6}[-(A-Z)]

Though this matches the first 7 characters, it doesn't match the whole string. Any help appreciated.

I am using Java and wanting .matches() to return true for this String

Comment: how about `^.{6}[-A-Z].*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Though this matches the first 7 characters, it doesn't match the whole string.

That's the right explanation of what is going on. You can skip over the rest of the string by adding `.*` at the end. Additionally, the `^` anchor at the front of the expression is implied, so you can drop it for a pattern of

```
.{6}[A-Z-].*
```

Comment: The `()` shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Andreas Right, I thought he wants parentheses too, but the text of his question suggests that he wants just letters and a dash. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4936904/pavneet-singh) You can use `.*` to match anything after your specific character so use

```
^.{6}[-A-Z].*
```

and also no need of `()` if you don't want to capture that specific character

Comment: Since the regex is for `matches()`, the `^` is redundant.

Comment: @Andreas yeah, just wants to respect the efforts of other answerer, thanks for the info!